# Silverstripe combine filterAny and filter to have an OR with an AND in it

Tags: silverstripe

I have a question and maybe somebody can help me figure out what the best way would be to achieve the solution. What i wanted to do is the reverse of:

http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/topics/datamodel#highlighter_745635

```
WHERE ("LastName" = 'Minnée' AND ("FirstName" = 'Sam' OR "Age" = '17'))
```

I want to get something along the lines of:

```
WHERE( ("LastName" = 'Minnée') OR ("FirstName" = 'Sam' AND "Age" = '17'))
```

Now i cannot find any way to achieve this effect seeing as i cannot add a filter within the filterAny

For now i am doing it with the get()->where( ... )  option but was more wondering with this question if their are alternative options without having to write normal SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

As 'AND' has a higher priority it doesn't need to be in braces. You can just write it as:

```
WHERE( "LastName" = 'Minnée' OR "FirstName" = 'Sam' AND "Age" = '17')
```

But as far as I can tell on the first look there isn't a way to write this without using where(). Let us know if you find a way. For debuging you can display the generated SQL-Query by calling the function sql():

```
... get()->where( ... )->sql();
```

Comment: Tried a few different things but in the end just gave up their is currently no way that i can tell (but i was wrong about templates to so don't quote me on it) to do nested filtering. Have an OR contain an AND and vice versa. Their have been some great suggestions over at: http://www.silverstripe.org/data-model-questions/show/72438#post370284

Comment: I started having a look at the DataQuery but after a bit building the query I stop. I decided that even if it works out the result would just be so bad to read. Thanks for posting the link :)