# Filtering a single field in a DataObject with multiple values

Tags: silverstripe, data-objects

I am trying to filter dataobject results based on checkbox selection.

If a user checks 'pool' and 'garage' I would like all items to display with a pool and a garage. At the moment only one or the other works but not together.

Something similar to: http://murcia.99apartments.com/rentals/ but without the Ajax.

Is this the correct way to go about this?

```
public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
$properties = Property::get();

   if($pool= $request->getVar('pool')) {
        $properties= $properties
        ->filter(array(
            'Title' => 'pool'              
        ));
    }

if($garage= $request->getVar('garage')) {
        $properties= $properties
        ->filter(array(
            'Title' => 'garage'              
        ));
    }

return array (
    'Results' => $properties
);
}
```

Comment: Does "filterAny" instead of just "filter" what your after?

Comment: Really need to see your db fields from each of the data objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silverstripe combine filterAny and filter to have an OR with an AND in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475089/silverstripe-combine-filterany-and-filter-to-have-an-or-with-an-and-in-it)

Comment: The above question should get you on track, just a tip though, make your checkboxes an array with the same name, eg `<input type='checkbox' name='filters[]'>` that way you don't have to have multiple GET variables and you can just rely on one, makes your code alot less bloated

Comment: Did you see the online lessons http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons ? It's a step-by-step tutorial how to build a property site, incl. relations, filtering, ajax etc....